# SQL Server 2012 Enterprise Edition No IP Address Option

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to figure out a way to connect my client computer to the server computer running SQL server 2012 enterprise edition. I posted a question earlier, and I thank everyone who helped, but unfortunately I still couldn't get it right.
Here is the link to my previous question...

[SQL Server 2012 Enterprise Edition ABLE TO CONNECT FROM SAME COMPUTER BUT NOT BY LAN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21403914/sql-server-2012-enterprise-edition-able-to-connect-from-same-computer-but-not-by?noredirect=1#comment32287349_21403914)

I have done steps in 2005 and 2008 and they worked perfectly. So now I'm back to square 1 to check everything because I'm out of ideas. I noticed SQL server configuration should have this property window under TCP/IP.

[image]

My SQL server configuration only has this...

[image]

Am I missing something here? Why don't I have the IP tab? Thank you very much.

Comment: Do you even have a TCP/IP channel configured? In SQL Server Configuration Manager, under "SQL Server Network Configuration", "Protocols for <instanceName>", is "TCP/IP" enabled?

Comment: That looks like the settings you see when looking at your *client* settings. The settings you need to change are the ones under `SQL Server Network Configuration -> Protocols for <Your Instance>`, on the *server*.

Comment: Thank you kind Sirs. Now I see them. Oh boy I'm dumb :)

Answer (score 1):

check TCP/IP settings under the correct instance of your SQL server

Answer (score 0):

check the instance you taken is correct. Take the TCP/IP properties under **sql server network configuration** in sql server configuration manager.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a powershell way to check to make sure that the TCP protocol is enabled:

```
$machineName = '.';
$instanceName = 'MSSQLSERVER';

$machine = new-object 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Wmi.ManagedComputer' $machineName
$machine.ServerInstances[$instanceName].ServerProtocols['Tcp'].isEnabled;
```

If you find that it's disabled, you can enable it with:

```
$machine.ServerInstances[$instanceName].ServerProtocols['Tcp'].isEnabled = $true;
$machine.ServerInstances[$instanceName].ServerProtocols['Tcp'].Alter();
```